Please help me understand implicit differentiation
$x^3(x + y) = y^2(8x − y)$
While I understand to start by using the product rule and treating y as a function of $x$, I don't feel like I fully understand what that means.
When we start on this problem we get
$$3x^2(x+y) + x^3(1+y') = 2yy'(8x-y) + y^2(8-y')$$
but I am struggling to understand why we have $2yy'$ as the derivative of $y^2$? I feel like an idiot but I don't get where the $y'$ is coming from and why it wouldn't just be  $2y'$. Sorry if this question is in an ugly format.

It's all about the chain rule. If $y=f(x)$, then the derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $x$ is the derivative of $(f(x))^2$, which, by the chain rule, is $2f(x)f'(x)$. The whole point of implicit differentiation is that you're assuming that locally $y$ is given as a differentiable function of $x$. Maybe it would help you to rewrite it with $f(x)$ in there a few times until you get used to it.

You can also view $x$ as a function of $y$ in which case  the derivative of $3x^3$ would be $9x^2\frac{dx}{dy}$. Take a look at the graph of that curve. It fails the vertical line test miserably. If you consider certain regions of the $x$ axis, you can see that $y$ is a function of $x$. (vertical line test) Likewise, there are sections of the $y$ axis where $x$ is a function of $y$. These regions are where implicit differentiation is valid.

there is no need to feel like an idiot! Everyone learns at their own pace, and you came to the correct place for help :)
Instead of immediately clicking on the spoiler reveal, please try to do it yourself first! That will be a great exercise.
Okey let's break it down. I assume you are familiar with the chain rule. So if we have a function $g\circ f(x)$ and we compute its derivative with respect to $x$ we obtain

 $$g'(f(x))f'(x).$$

When we read your equation $x^3(x+y) = y^2(8x-y)$ we think of $y$ as being a function of $x$. So we have $x^3(x+y(x)) = (y(x))^2 (8x - y(x))$, we just omit writing $y(x)$ for convenience. Now if we take the derivative of $y(x)$ with respect to $x$ we obtain $y'(x)$, right! And if $f(x)=x^2$ and we want to take the derivative of $(y(x))^2 = f(y(x))$ we should use the chain rule to obtain

 $$\frac{d}{dx}f(y(x)) = f'(y(x))y'(x) = 2y(x)y'(x).$$

So if we put this together we obtain the desired result! Using the product rule and chain rule (with $y$ being a function of $x$, so $y(x)$) we obtain
$$3x^2(x+y(x)) + x^3 (1+y'(x)) = 2y(x)y'(x)(8x-y(x)) + (y(x))^2(8-y'(x)).$$
Let add an exercise for you! Consider the equation $x^2\sin (y^2) + \cos (x) = 4y^{-3}(x^2 + e^{5y})$. Take the derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides. Hint: $y$ is a function of $x$, so we have $y(x)$.
The answer is here below:

 $$2x\sin(y^2) + x^2\cos(y^2)2y y' -\sin(x) = -12y^{-4}y'(x^2+e^{5y}) + 4y^{-3}(2x + 5y'e^{5y}). $$

I hope this makes more sense to you and you are now able to do implicit differentiation by yourself!

Let $u$ be a function of $v$ and $v$ be a function of $x$. The chain rule says that the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$, is the derivative of $u$ with respect to $v$ times the derivative of $v$ with respect to $x$. In other words,
$$u'=\frac{du}{dv}.v'$$
For example, if $y$ is a function of $x,$
$$(y^2)'=\frac{d(y^2)}{dy}.y'=2yy'.$$
Another example,
$$(\ln\sin x)'=\frac{d(\ln\sin x)}{d(\sin x)}(\sin x)'=\frac1{\sin x}\cos x=\cot x.$$
